# How can I find the minimum value for a field each day over a timespan using RethinkDb?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a database of readings from weather sensors. One of the items measured is 'sky temperature'. I want to find the minimum sky temperature each day over a period of a month or two.

The first thing I tried was this:

```
r.db('Weather').table('TAO_SkyNet', {readMode:'outdated'})
  .group(r.row('time').dayOfYear(),{index:'time'})
  .min('sky')
```

I think that might work, except that it is a large database and the query times out after 300 seconds. Fair enough, I really don't want the data back to the beginning of time. A few weeks will do. So I tried to restrict the records examined like this:

```
r.db('Weather').table('TAO_SkyNet', {readMode:'outdated'})
  .between(r.time(2018,3,1,'Z'), r.now())
  .group(r.row('time').dayOfYear(),{index:'time'})
  .min('sky')
```

..and I get...

```
e: Expected type TABLE but found TABLE_SLICE:
SELECTION ON table(TAO_SkyNet) in:
r.db("Weather").table("TAO_SkyNet", {"readMode": "outdated"}).between(r.time(2018, 3, 1, "Z"), r.now()).group(r.row("time").dayOfYear(), {"index": "time"}).min("sky")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, I'm stuck here. How do I group on a subset of the table?

Answer (score 1):

`between` returns a table slice, and table slices don't support indexes.

> table.between(lowerKey, upperKey[, options]) → table_slice

By the way, `between` operates over indexes itself.
Once you remove `{index:'time'}` from your `group` clause (if `TAO_SkyNet` has `time` as its primary key):

```javascript
r.db('Weather')
    .table('TAO_SkyNet', {readMode: 'outdated'})
    .between(r.time(2018, 3, 1, 'Z'), r.now())
    .group(r.row('time').dayOfYear())
    .min('sky')
```

or move the `index` option to the `between` clause (if `TAO_SkyNet` has `time` as its secondary key)

```javascript
r.db('Weather')
    .table('TAO_SkyNet', {readMode: 'outdated'})
    .between(r.time(2018, 3, 1, 'Z'), r.now(), {index: 'time'})
    .group(r.row('time').dayOfYear())
    .min('sky')
```

it should work fine.
Test dataset:

```javascript
r.db('Weather').table('TAO_SkyNet').insert([
    // day 1
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 1,  0, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 10},
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 1,  8, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 4}, // min
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 1, 16, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 7},
    // day 2
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 2,  0, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 2}, // min
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 2,  8, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 4},
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 2, 16, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 9},
    // day 3
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 3,  0, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 7},
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 3,  8, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 7},
    {time: r.time(2018, 3, 3, 16, 0, 0, 'Z'), sky: 1} // min
]);
```

Query result:

```
[{
    "group": 60,
    "reduction": {"sky": 4, "time": Thu Mar 01 2018 08:00:00 GMT+00:00}
},
{
    "group": 61,
    "reduction": {"sky": 2, "time": Fri Mar 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+00:00}
},
{
    "group": 62,
    "reduction": {"sky": 1, "time": Sat Mar 03 2018 16:00:00 GMT+00:00}
}]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. 'time' is a secondary index and not necessarily unique. Does that alter anything?

Comment: I'm staggered by how long this query takes to run, even distributed over 3 shards. New items are added to the database about every 5 seconds, so there are about 17,280 documents per day added to the database. So the query above, over just a single day's worth of data (which already negates the purpose of the `groupBy()` never completes and times out after 300 seconds (in the web interface). Now I would really like to run the query over 2 to 6 months worth of data. Do I in fact need a completely different approach?

Comment: @TimLong How long does it take to calculate the _min_ for a single day?

Comment: about 14.46 seconds. I'm still kinda surprised at that since there are 3 shards working on it. If I do it twice, the second time takes less than 700 milliseconds. I guess the cache is working!